# Неизменный обратный таймер

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Не подскажите, как сделать 30 секундный обратный таймер на странице, который не меняется при обновлении страницы или при изменении пользователем часового пояса на устройстве. Буду благодарен.

Answer (score 0):

Вот как самый примитивный вариант :) Часовой пояс можно игнорировать путем общего для всех серверного времени (серверного объекта `Date()` ) который пропускать через тот же `setInterval(callback,1000);`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title class="timerForTitle">Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<script>
   if(!sessionStorage.timerForTitle){
       sessionStorage.timerForTitle = 30;
   }

  var timer =  setInterval(function () {
      var count = Number(sessionStorage.timerForTitle);
      if(--count >= 0){
          sessionStorage.timerForTitle = count;
          document.querySelector('.timerForTitle').innerHTML = 'Title '+count;
      }else{
          document.querySelector('.timerForTitle').innerHTML = 'Title finish';
        sessionStorage.timerForTitle = 30;
        clearInterval(timer);
        // тут перенаправление
      }
  },1000);

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: А как сделать редирект на др. страницу после окончания таймера?

Comment: по окончанию допишите window.location = 'www.mySite.ru';

Comment: Ещё вопрос:Сделал редирект. После окончания таймера страница timer.php перенаправляет пользователя на timeend.php. Когда пользователь хочет обратно на timer.php таймер не срабатывает и сразу происходит редирект на timeend.php. Каким-то образом можно исправить это(убить сессию timerForTitle)?

Comment: можете по окончанию добавлять в хранилище метку что именно этот тайм окончен и при редиректе ... то есть инициализации таймера проверять эту метку и если она есть то сбрасывать таймер иначе продолжать

Comment: Можете показать пример

Comment: обновил пример.

Comment: Отлично. Последний вопрос: находясь на странице timer.php можно ли как-то продлить время таймера до редиректа на timeend.php (допустим, если пользователь оказался "хакером")

Comment: возле самого редиректа делайте проверку, если это  'хакер' то добавьте 30 сек и проигнорьте редирект. Но я бы просто при редиректе либо в url либо в post запросе отправлял значение таймера и если он  равен 0 то выдавал то что надо иначе обратный редирект

Comment: Не совсем понял. Если будет время напишите пример)), буду благодарен.